# Interchange of summation and max operator

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Is there any conditions under which the following holds:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i \max_{x} f_i(x) = \max_{x} \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i  f_i(x)
\end{align}
where $\alpha_i >0, \forall i \in I$ and f_i's have the same domain.

Comment: The set of indices is arbitrary?

Comment: @Azif00 Let's say I = {1,2,...,N}

Comment: I'd just like to make sure that each $f_i$ has the same domain and maxima are taken over the domain. Also are there any assumptions on the $\alpha_i$'s or are these also things that are subject to conditions?

Comment: @OliverClarke Edited the question. The answer to your questions would be yes!

Comment: This equation holds very rarely. If all the functions attain their maximum at the same point then it is true. It fails most  situations.

Comment: So if the domain of the functions is some ordered set, then you could say that the equality holds if all the functions are weakly increasing (or weakly decreasing) since the maxima are attained by taking the largest (or smallest) value for $x$. However I highly doubt the converse holds. And for non-ordered domains, it seems very difficult to say anything